# Simple Nodejs web server always sends text/plain css and js files

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, http, google-chrome

I'm running into a weird problem when creating a simple web server in `Nodejs`. The http server runs fine and accepts requests and responses like it should. However, for some reason it always wants to send a `content-type:` of `text/plain` for everything. For example, `.js` and `.css` files always come down as `text/plain` whereas they should normally be sent as  `text/css` or `application/javascript`.  Chrome, the browser I'm using to test this, always complains about the MIME type of the resource:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:3000/test.css".`

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:3000/test-client.js".`

What this ultimately means is the `css` is never applied to the page. I've added some logging and it appears that the http response is sending down the correct MIME type.

I've created a barebones version of what I'm doing. Hopefully someone can point out the flaw that I've coded:

**test.js**

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url'),
    path = require('path');
var contentTypes = {
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.css': "text/css",
    '.js': 'application/javascript'
};
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // get file based on pathname
    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname,
        filename = path.join(__dirname, uri);
    fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
        // if root directory, append test.html
        if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) {
            filename += 'test.html';
        }
        // figure out MIME type by file ext
        var contentType = contentTypes[path.extname(filename)];
        fs.readFile(filename, function(err, file) {
            // errors?
            if (err) {
                response.writeHead(404, {'Content-type:': 'text/plain'});
                response.write(err + "\n");
                response.end();
            } else {
                console.log('MIME TYPE for: ', filename , contentType);
                response.setHeader('Content-Type:', contentType);
                response.writeHead(200);
                response.write(file);
                response.end();
            }
        });
    });
}).listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server started and listening on port 3000");
});
```

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test-client.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.css**

```css
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

**test-client.js**

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');
div.innerHTML = 'test client ran successfully';
```

Comment: when setting headers, you don't really do it right. To the extent of my knowledge, you shouldn't use `response.setHeader`, instead do `response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'contentType'});` and also, in the error handler, for the options on `writeHead` you did `{'Content-Type:','something-or/other'}` but there shouldn't be that `:` after `Content-Type`: it should just be  `Content-Type`

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark the question as solved - however, on Stack Overflow, the tick is fine `:)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using an unnecessary `:` after `Content-Type` when setting headers. You should either do `response.setHeader('Content-Type',contentType);` or, which I think is even better, do this: `response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':contentType});`

Comment: w00t! **Thank you so much!** That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

And you must made `fs.readFile` wrapped by a closure, otherwise some file (especially the last file) will be read more than once, and others will not be read at all. And the `contentType`will not be set as you wish. This is because of the callback strategy used by `fs.readFile`. The problem does not appear when the html file just load one external file, but as the external files(css, js, png) loaded more than one it will appear as i pointed out above. (I cannot login with my gmail so I post as a guest)

So your code should make a little change as follows:

```
;(function (filename, contentType) {

    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, file) {
        // do the left stuff here
    });

}(filename, contentType));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, however mine was caused slightly differently. I was initially using this method to set the `Content_Type`:

`res.writeHead(200, { 'Content_Type': contentType });`

After replacing it with the following the errors disappeared:

`res.setHeader('Content-Type',contentType)`